# JPA 2.0 EntityManager merge remove a reference do nothing

Tags: java, spring, jpa, merge, jpa-2.0

i'm trying to remove a child from a parent entity (without delete the reference from the DB) using merge, what i do is get the collection of a @OneToMany field from the parent and then remove from the collection and finally i use merge, this works when i use the same approach but adding instead of removing, the entities are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bills")
public class Bill {

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="bill")
    private Set<BillDetail> billDetails = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="billDetails")
public class BillDetail {

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="bill")
    private Bill bill;

    ...
}
```

the code where i do the merge are:

```
Collection<Object> references = (Collection<Object>) PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty(parentEntity, referenceField);
references.remove(childEntity); // the adding are the same, only i change remove for add here
PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(parentEntity, referenceField,references);

requirementCheck.setData(childEntity);

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.merge(parentEntity);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

entityManager.close();
```

So i do not see any update log when i remove, what i'm missing? i'm using @Transactional on the class that do the merge and i use aspectj and Spring AOP thogether (ensuring that there is not appling an AOP and an Aspectj to the same method) also i'm using Hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship is owned by the BillDetail instance, so any changes to the relationship will require changes to the BillDetail,  and that the BillDetail be merged.

It works when adding because the merge is able to cascade over the relationship so that the changes in the BillDetail are also merged.  When removing the reference, you sever this reference, preventing the cascade options to find your BillDetail instance, so you manually have to call merge on it after clearing its bill reference.

Comment: if i understand, what i need to do is unset the Bill in the BillDetail, remove the BillDetail from the collection and then make a merge? but the merge must be applied to BillDetail or over the Bill?

Comment: You changed both instances, so both need to be merged to keep your JPA caches insync.  The database will reflect the change though if you just merge the change to BillDetail

Comment: i forgot to tell that parentEntity in this case is Bill and childEntity is BillDetail, i try also to merge both but nothing happen, the order for merge matters?

Comment: it finally works, what i do first is remove from the collection in parentEntity like in the above code, then unset the parentEntity in the childEntity, and finally merge first child and then parentEntity, but now in my addReference method the register is duplicated with a different id, in this method i create childEntity with persist if the id is null, then i add the reference to parentEntity but when is merge i get a insert again (when i debugg the childEntity has an id) so i get two inserts, one in persist and one in merge